# Evaluate 1/tanh(x) - 1/x for very small x

Tags: python, numpy, math, rounding

I need to compute the quantity

```
1/tanh(x) - 1/x
```

for `x > 0`, where `x` can be both very small and very large.

Asymptotically for small `x`, we have

```
1/tanh(x) - 1/x  ->  x / 3
```

and for large `x`

```
1/tanh(x) - 1/x  ->  1
```

Anyhow, when computing the expression, already from `10^-7` and smaller round-off errors lead to the expression being evaluated as exactly 0:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = numpy.array([2**k for k in range(-30, 30)])
y = 1.0 / numpy.tanh(x) - 1.0 / x

plt.loglog(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you could define your own version of the function `1/tanh(x) - 1/x`  which would evaluate the asymptotic expressions if the argument is too small/large

Comment: Write your own `tanh`?  (I'm not seeing it go to 0 until less than 10^-8.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For very small `x`, one could use [the Taylor expansion of `1/tanh(x) - 1/x` around `0`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+of+1%2Ftanh(x)+-+1%2Fx),

```
y = x/3.0 - x**3 / 45.0 + 2.0/945.0 * x**5
```

The error is of the order `O(x**7)`, so if `10^-5` is chosen as the breaking point, relative and absolute error will be well below machine precision.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = numpy.array([2**k for k in range(-50, 30)])

y0 = 1.0 / numpy.tanh(x) - 1.0 / x
y1 = x/3.0 - x**3 / 45.0 + 2.0/945.0 * x**5
y = numpy.where(x > 1.0e-5, y0, y1)


plt.loglog(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. Moving to arbitrary-precision arithmetic just to avoid a Taylor expansion adds massive complexity, dependency, storage, and computational costs (and I say this as someone who likes mpmath very much!)

Answer (score 3):

Use the python package [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/doc/0.19/index.html) for arbitrary decimal precision.  For example:

```
import mpmath
from mpmath import mpf

mpmath.mp.dps = 100 # set decimal precision

x = mpf('1e-20')

print (mpf('1') / mpmath.tanh(x)) - (mpf('1') / x)
>>> 0.000000000000000000003333333333333333333333333333333333333333311111111111111111111946629156220629025294373160489201095913
```

It gets extremely precise.

Look into [`mpmath` plotting](http://mpmath.org/doc/0.19/plotting.html).  `mpmath` plays well with `matplotlib`, which you are using, so this should solve your problem.

---

Here is an example of how to integrate mpmath into the code you wrote above:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpmath
from mpmath import mpf

mpmath.mp.dps = 100 # set decimal precision

x = numpy.array([mpf('2')**k for k in range(-30, 30)])
y = mpf('1.0') / numpy.array([mpmath.tanh(e) for e in x]) - mpf('1.0') / x

plt.loglog(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A probably simpler solution to overcome this is changing the data type under which numpy is operating:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-30, 30, dtype=np.longdouble)
x = 2**x
y = 1.0 / np.tanh(x) - 1.0 / x

plt.loglog(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Using `longdouble` as data type does give the proper solution without rounding errors.

---

I did sightly modify your example, in your case the only thing you need to modify is:

```
x = numpy.array([2**k for k in range(-30, 30)])
```

to:

```
x = numpy.array([2**k for k in range(-30, 30)], dtype=numpy.longdouble)
```

Comment: I tried this and noticed it fails just a little bit later, at 10^-10.