# numpy 2D-array divide precise lost

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I got some troubles when did numpy 2d-array divide. 
I have a 2D numpy array A (shape=(N,N)), then i divide it by row_sum(axis=1) and got 2D-array B, but when i computed the row_sum(axis=1) of B, is not equal to **one** at some rows, the code is followed:
 (python2.7.x)

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[x_11, x_12, ..., x_1N],
              [x_21, x_22, ..., x_2N],
              [...   ...   ...  ... ]
              [x_N1, x_N2, ..., x_NN]]) # x_ij are some np.float64 values
B = A / np.sum(A, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Theoretically result:

```
np.count_nonzero(np.sum(B, axis=1) != 1)
# it should be 0
```

Reality result:

```
np.count_nonzero(np.sum(B, axis=1) != 1)
# something bigger than 0
```

I believe the reason is **precise lost**, though i use the dtype=np.float64. Because in my project, the A 2D-array (shape=(N, N), N>8000), most of the values is very small(eg. =1.0) and the others are very big(eg. =2000) at the same row.

I have try this: Add the losts

```
while np.count_nonzero(np.sum(B, axis=1) != 1) != 0
    losts = 1 - B
    B[:, i] += losts # the i may change by some conditions
```

Though, finally it can solve this problems, but is not good for next step in my project.

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Maybe you meant : `np.count_nonzero(np.sum(B, axis=1) != 1)`? I am guessing you should be using `~np.isclose(..,1)` instead of `!=1`.

Comment: oh, yes! it's a typo :), and i have changed it.

Comment: the row sum of arrray B must be all equal to one, not close to one within a tolerance in my projcet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with floating numbers you get loss in precision and floating numbers very hardly match **exactly** natural numbers.

A simple test to demonstrate this is:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3
False
```

This is because the floatting point representation of `0.1 + 0.2` is `0.30000000000000004`.

To solve this you just need to switch to [np.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy.isclose) or [np.allclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html):

```
import numpy as np

N = 100
A = np.random.randn(N, N)
B = A / np.sum(A, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Then:

```
>>> np.count_nonzero(np.sum(B, axis=1) != 1)
79
```

whereas

```
>>> np.allclose(np.sum(B, axis=1), 1)
True
```

In short, your rows are properly normalized, they just don't sum **exactly** to 1.

---

From the documentation `np.isclose(a, b)` is equivalent to:

> `absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))`

with `atol = 1e-8` and `rtol = 1e-5` (by default), which is the proper way of comparing that two floating point numbers represent *the same number* (or at least, approximately).

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But In my project, i need use the array B to compute other things, and it need the row sum of B is equal to one, or will not proper. So i must let the row sum equal to one, not close. Sorry for my unclear questions :(

Comment: @babaozhouy5 The error introduced by floating points is extremely small `(np.sum(B, axis=1) - 1).mean() => 1.9872992140790302e-16`. Do you really need more than 1e-16 precision? The number is essentially `1`, there is just no way to ensure it with floating point operations. You can cast your data to `.astype(np.longdouble)` for extra precision (up to `-2.87313575708658675e-20`).

Comment: @babaozhouy5 Essentially, you are going to have that loss in precision, you want it or not. If it is not now, it is going to be later in some other operation. It is nothing wrong about numpy, just floating point representation on computers in general. The question you have to ask yourself is what is an *acceptable precision loss* for your application. It varies a lot from just basic operations, computer vision, machine learning or if you are designing a new engine for a modern airplane. Even if you use that `B` later, for 99% of the applications you wont care of the precision loss.

Comment: Oh, I see! The precision is definitely lost, i shouldn't focus on that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to control the precision up to `N` digits, you can have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43279232/764322) which uses `mpmath` to *trick* numpy arrays, but as I said before, this lose of precision is completely natural when representing floating point numbers in computers, and for most applications is not important.

Comment: That package is amazing Σ( ° △ °|||). I will try this, but like you said, i should have an acceptable precision loss! But anyway, thank you so much!